# .NET 2 / VB: RequestValidation = false alternatives

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am experiencing an issue with a web app that is frequently spewing out the following style error with just a single aspx page:

```
Browser: IE
Url Referrer: redacted
User Host 1.1.1.1
User Host Name: 1.1.1.1
Last Error: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl11$lbl="...na Redacte w..."). at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String s, String valueName, String collectionName) at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateNameValueCollection(NameValueCollection nvc, String collectionName) at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm() at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull) at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at ASP.pages_front_closingques_default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
Stack Trace: at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String s, String valueName, String collectionName) at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateNameValueCollection(NameValueCollection nvc, String collectionName) at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm() at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull) at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at ASP.pages_front_closingques_default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
Source: System.Web
Message: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl11$lbl="...na Redacte w...").
```

Normally, I would suspect that the user must have done something dumb like put an HTML tag in there, but this happens frequently and no HTML tags are reported in the email.

I know that I can turn *off* `ValidateRequest` using the `RequestValidation="false"` `Page` directive, but that is also undesirable because I want some validation, just not over-sensitive validation.

Is there some way I can override the default implementation of `ValidateRequest`? Has anybody run into `ValidateRequest` erroneously producing errors before? Finally, does anybody know what the implementation of `ValidateRequest` even looks like?

Comment: Why have you included the term "classic" in this question's title?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones, I am mostly new to Microsoft stack and from what I understand there is a distinction between "classic" ASP vs ASP.NET and "Classic" VB vs VB.net...

Comment: But I agree the title is terrible... suggestions?

Comment: "Classic VB" is VB6 not .NET, so nix that from your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that the false positives are coming from just the one page, I would keep the site level web.config setting enabled, and disable the page level validation for just this page.

Then you need to take responsibility for user input on the page:

- Do your own (server side) validation on all fields, e.g. regex etc.
- Sanitize any data known to be user originated input before writing it out, e.g. with [WPL](http://wpl.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Isn't there a difference though between _request_ validator (ie the GET or POST in question) and _input_ validator (something that happens ostensibly before the request is made)